# Code::Blocks with gdb showing unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, gdb, codeblocks

I'm trying to use gdb with Code::Blocks, and am encountering issues. I can run the program fine, and the debugger will stop on specific errors. However, if I try to use backtrace, everything is listed as in ?? (). Print also returns `No symbol in current context` regardless of the variable chosen.

I'm wondering if it is an issue with CodeBlocks, but can't determine the issue.

Comment: This normally means that you didn't compile with debug info.  Try adding `-g`.

Comment: Not really an option in CodeBlocks, there is just a compile and debug button.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that once I had entered an infinite loop, and then paused execution, certain debugging didn't work. If I step through the code slowly I can read the variables fine.